# Tensorflowjs predict_classes

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to import a cnn classifier in javascript with tensorflowjs and make some predictions. Is there a method like keras predict_classes, which gives me just one number representing the class the model is predicting? I can use the normal model.predict, but I'm getting back a tensor and I'm struggling to iterate over it to find the highest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no method such as `predict_classes`. But you can do the following.

```
const predictClasses = model.predict(input);
// this is considering that your predictClasses looks something like this [1,2,3]
const yourClass = predictClasses.argMax(-1).dataSync()[0]
```

API document for [reference](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#argMax).

Comment: Hello @Paul https://stackoverflow.com/users/10766966/paul, did my answer clear your query?